# Android orientation change

Tags: android

I am working on a project. where i used screen orientation landscape and portrait. I also use `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"` so that activity not refresh when switch orientation .

Now app is unable  to switch from layout-port->layout-land xml  layout as i use configChanges = "orientation" .

I am able switch from  Landscape-> portrait   or portrait->Landscape but it show the layout-port xml from both orientation rather than switch from layout-port->layout-land or
layout-land->layout-port.

Comment: you sohuldnt use android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" to handle orientation changes.. Check out onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState

Comment: Let's be clear.  `android:configChanges="orientation"` is a hack.  It should only be used in very special circumstances.  There is plenty of discussion if you search on why it's bad (very bad).  In short, you cover up bugs which will show up later in other scenarios.  The right answer is to learn the Activity life cycle and code according to that.  This hack is the lazy persons way to cover up problems in their code which are still there waiting to be found.

Answer (score 0):

add this in ur activity

```
inside of oncreate()
if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation ==Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) 
        setContentView(R.layout.land);
else if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation ==Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) 
        setContentView(R.layout.port);



@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration config) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(config);


    if (config.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        setContentView(R.layout.land);
    } else if (config.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        setContentView(R.layout.port);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using layout and layout-land but it is showing layout xml in both land and port view not switch to layout-land.

Answer (score 0):

In AndroidManifest file add only `android:configChanges="orientation"` and remove the other two for the activity you want to handle this orientation

Answer (score 0):

try this

change `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"`

to `android:configChanges="orientation"`

and on your activity, override `onConfigurationChanged` methode

like Manivannan describes in his response

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration config) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(config);


    if (config.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        //set your landscape layout
    } else if (config.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        //the same for portrait layout
    }
}
```

that's it.

Comment: Thanks...I follow you answer...if i use only android:configChanges="orientation" the activity reload on orientation change..i want not to reload activity on orientation change

Comment: than add screenSize to android:configChanges

Comment: In API level 13 or above, the screen size changes when the orientation changes, so this still causes the activity to be destroyed and started when orientation changes